# After uninstall oracle, there is remaining directory. 'tfa'

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

After uninstall ORACLE is complete, I can see 'product' directory is removed and I checked sqlplus is not available anymore. The final message looked fine.

However, there is a remaining or replaced directory, which is named `tfa`. I've searched it and it is a kind of tool to help us find out what's going on.

My questions are:

1. Why isn't it uninstalled?
2. Is it installed automatically at the same time of ORACLE install?
3. Can I remove it with `rm` command?
4. After uninstall, what kind of things do I have to check?

My ORACLE version is 12c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. TFA is a seperate installation. It is not part of the database home. Uninstalling the database home does not automatically uninstall TFA.
2. It is installed while executing root.sh, but it is a seperate installation.
3. No. Uninstall it with `$ORACLE_BASE/tfa/$(hostname -s)/tfa_home/bin/uninstalltfa.sh`, as root user.
4. None.